# Changing between two models seemlessly

Tags: modeling

Blender Newb here. Just downloaded the software today and I'm falling in love with it. However:

I'm trying to do an Intro / spinny thing (not the dubstep type) and I can't seem to figure out how.

What I have done:

-I have two seperate models (1 and 2 in image below) in Blender of the same object, but with different text on it. Since I'm a Noob I created the models in different Software and just "subtracted" (?) the text in tinkercad.

-I have animated the Object you see in the Bottom (Berufsmesse Zürich) to slowly rise up, spin around a couple times and then stop.

What I want to do:

-Once the spin stops, I want the text to say what the upper model says (Dienstag)

My questions:

-How can I get Object 2 (Dienstag) to replace Object 1 seamlessly?

-Would replacing Object 1 with Object 2 in a moment where the Object 1 is facing away from the camera work?

-Is there an easier way to do this?

-When does Blender stop being so frustrating? :D

Thank you in advance for your response!

Also yes, I have attempted to google this but didn't come up with anything.

[image]

Comment: "*Would replacing Object 1 with Object 2 in a moment where the Object 1 is facing away from the camera work?*" Sounds like the most immediate way of achieving this. Just animate the visibility property of both objects at the correct moment, so one goes hidden, and the other becomes visible.

Comment: You could also animate the material's transparency, or render the clip once for each object and then crossfade/cut the video.